# Safari view in swiftui displaying empty view

Tags: swiftui, sfsafariviewcontroller, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-environment

Hi everyone I am trying to display safari view as full screen modal using ZStack

```
        ZStack
        {
            HStack
            {
                VStack
                {
                    Safari(url: url)
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .offset(x: 0, y: self.modalPresented ? 0 : 5000)
```

But the output I get is a white empty view. And also the navigation bar is still visible.
Can someone please help me explain what is going on? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqd64.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is how we call a url :

```
url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com") 
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

If you are using Scene delegate, then you should handle url first, so go to Scene delegate and add this fuction, if it does not exists already:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {

    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }

    //Handle URL here
}
```

Then you url call should be like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```